# Get list in json

Tags: python, json, list, png

I get json file from the annotation software. I want only a point to generate a PNG images but json file contain all other data. How could I get the list of which contain only point so, I can convert it to PNG.

This is my json file look like. I want only exterior part in point in objects.

```
{'description': '', 'tags': [], 'size': {'height': 3520, 'width': 1980}, 'objects': [{'description': '', 'geometryType': 'polygon', 'labelerLogin': 'peerawit.kh', 'tags': [], 'classTitle': 'Chicken', 'points': {'exterior': [[462, 1015], [524, 954], [588, 930], [671, 875], [727, 841], [762, 860], [806, 878], [840, 878], [883, 873], [948, 919], [1009, 962], [1049, 986], [1081, 980], [1112, 1005], [1132, 1032], [1160, 1082], [1178, 1130], [1184, 1165], [1191, 1200], [1216, 1227], [1253, 1246], [1272, 1248], [1221, 1308], [1227, 1335], [1234, 1355], [1250, 1361], [1297, 1350], [1336, 1347], [1387, 1351], [1425, 1371], [1457, 1375], [1479, 1382], [1509, 1407], [1557, 1466], [1602, 1500], [1596, 1527], [1538, 1540], [1532, 1554], [1570, 1589], [1605, 1621], [1640, 1653], [1680, 1691], [1698, 1729], [1709, 1752], [1685, 1745], [1624, 1710], [1538, 1678], [1557, 1702], [1577, 1750], [1612, 1780], [1594, 1841], [1587, 1882], [1615, 1943], [1624, 1900], [1633, 1881], [1643, 1864], [1648, 1842], [1651, 1825], [1655, 1810], [1665, 1805], [1673, 1809], [1685, 1828], [1693, 1842], [1688, 1877], [1695, 1884], [1709, 1899], [1717, 1914], [1720, 1937], [1726, 1956], [1727, 1970], [1723, 1987], [1718, 2002], [1735, 2037], [1750, 2062], [1743, 2089], [1747, 2111], [1761, 2144], [1774, 2174], [1784, 2168], [1789, 2159], [1796, 2153], [1801, 2166], [1790, 2184], [1787, 2191], [1775, 2203], [1770, 2214], [1764, 2225], [1768, 2231], [1787, 2249], [1793, 2259], [1801, 2276], [1793, 2293], [1796, 2318], [1802, 2322], [1816, 2325], [1826, 2334], [1833, 2333], [1851, 2319], [1860, 2314], [1872, 2310], [1890, 2299], [1903, 2281], [1916, 2266], [1929, 2254], [1942, 2244], [1956, 2239], [1962, 2241], [1980, 2233], [1980, 2348], [1967, 2357], [1956, 2366], [1936, 2380], [1925, 2389], [1914, 2403], [1895, 2420], [1882, 2434], [1868, 2452], [1853, 2468], [1841, 2486], [1828, 2497], [1826, 2517], [1817, 2557], [1808, 2616], [1801, 2696], [1786, 2795], [1756, 2927], [1707, 2990], [1657, 3049], [1608, 3049], [1539, 3053], [1483, 3025], [1428, 2993], [1390, 2971], [1214, 3130], [1141, 3257], [1060, 3289], [973, 3289], [852, 3232], [816, 3143], [716, 3005], [680, 2814], [566, 2730], [413, 2455], [362, 2281], [345, 2071], [302, 1997], [258, 1914], [190, 1820], [145, 1774], [101, 1746], [47, 1697], [28, 1687], [3, 1634], [14, 1617], [50, 1625], [98, 1661], [139, 1687], [183, 1702], [205, 1706], [243, 1742], [279, 1723], [285, 1706], [285, 1680], [253, 1625], [234, 1585], [222, 1530], [219, 1489], [228, 1432], [241, 1383], [245, 1334], [245, 1283], [241, 1235], [228, 1203], [228, 1179], [228, 1154], [231, 1110], [236, 1092], [248, 1073], [285, 1153], [292, 1186], [300, 1203], [313, 1264], [330, 1313], [334, 1375], [330, 1415], [338, 1453], [373, 1508], [396, 1477], [400, 1453], [406, 1394], [406, 1363], [432, 1353], [453, 1339], [461, 1345], [468, 1362], [474, 1409], [449, 1455], [436, 1489], [419, 1542], [408, 1578], [408, 1629], [410, 1670], [408, 1714], [436, 1778], [442, 1803], [438, 1850], [449, 1938], [451, 1958], [504, 1924], [542, 1944], [565, 1958], [618, 1997], [644, 2014], [680, 2028], [701, 2035], [737, 2039], [782, 2018], [805, 1994], [810, 1975], [812, 1941], [790, 1922], [746, 1899], [712, 1873], [697, 1852], [678, 1823], [661, 1791], [644, 1759], [580, 1740], [561, 1740], [536, 1729], [508, 1723], [472, 1725], [474, 1672], [508, 1612], [568, 1544], [629, 1558], [735, 1573], [803, 1567], [890, 1512], [848, 1462], [882, 1438], [831, 1390], [799, 1370], [748, 1341], [692, 1309], [663, 1298], [640, 1305], [574, 1341], [587, 1322], [625, 1288], [655, 1260], [686, 1241], [722, 1226], [763, 1188], [780, 1167], [765, 1137], [688, 1082], [650, 1054], [599, 1035], [532, 1032], [512, 1027], [504, 1024]], 'interior': []}}
```

This is my code. I tried somthings like d['objects']['points']['exteriors']. It not works because point is the list. What my c should be??
    from PIL import Image
    import json

```
OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (1980, 3520) #png image shape
json_name = 'gdrive/My Drive/DIP_chicken/json/'+'1'+'.json' #change only number of picture name
png_name =  'gdrive/My Drive/DIP_chicken/gt/'+'1'+'.png'

#read json file
with open(json_name) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d['objects'])
    c = d['objects']['points']
```

Thank you all

Comment: `d["objects"]` is quite clearly a list. You need `d['objects'][0]['points']`. There is nothing special about JSON; it's just deserialized to lists and dictionaries (in this case), so take the 0th index of that list. Your JSON is incomplete, so maybe there are more entries in that list

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:json.net] which is a *is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.*  You're not actually using this, correct?  If so I'd like to remove the tag, to eliminate confusion.